# Onedrive VBA getting share link of a file

Tags: vba, excel, onedrive

my question is rather simple but I've spent several hours googling trying to find a straight forward solution but I haven't found it.

Basically, using vba I want to save an Excel file to oneDrive's public folder which automatically will upload the file to the cloud, and I want to get a share link to that file so I can include it in an automatically generated email. I can already generate the automated email using vba and saving the file to the onedrive folder wouldn't be a problem I think but I want to include the share link before sending the email

I've read a little bit about rest and I have found info on how to communicate with one drive using a number of different programming languages but I haven't found any example vba interacting with onedrive.

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

This may help you get started: `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "c:\User\\OneDrive\public folder name\" & name you want to give this file & ".xls"` to save, and you have to use HTML tags for the hyperlink:

```
olEmail.HTMLBody = "<body><p>Here is my hyperlink: " & _
                               "<a href='path to the folder'></a>"
```

Comment: Thanks for your response @justkrys but if I replace the "path to the folder" part in `<a href='path to the folder'></a>` I would be using my local path right? how would the recipients of the link be able to  download the file from the cloud and also, wouldn't they need some sort of permission to access the file?

Comment: You would set it to whatever the path of the link to its location in the cloud is. As for permissions, if it requires them, then yes, they would have to.

Comment: Thanks again @justkrys, the thing is that a new file will be created each time and I don't know what the path to the link of the file will be, that's the main issue.

Comment: Hmm perhaps you can create a few new files and see if there is any commonality in the path.

Comment: This question is a little outdated, are you still looking for an answer?